# Trying to access a specific question causes the connection to reset

Tags: support, specific-question

It seems that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827794/need-help-decoding-obfuscated-code) causes the connection to reset, rather than showing the question or even displaying a "Not Found" page or another error page. This is not the case for most other questions, so this is truly unusual.

Comment: Does the dupe target [How does this giant regex work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3328235) also reset for you? Then fix your virus scanner..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question works for me, but it contains obfuscated code that is likely an exploit or backdoor. I would guess that a virus scanner or similar is removing the code and preventing you from loading the page.

Comment: You may be right.  As long as the answers doesn't depend on the specific code, someone ought to edit the code to neuter it.

Comment: @PeterO.: no, someone ought to fix that virus scanner if it's triggering on code that's not actually executable.